# Jquery Modal closes automatically with AJAX

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a form (made with HTML and PHP) with two buttons. One of the button simply save the form (INSERT OR UPDATE) and the another one do the same plus sending an email.

I have jquery modal in order to confirm the submit action everytime one of the buttons is pressed. After pressing the button there's another modal that appear only to confirm that the proccess was terminated without any errors.

My problem is that when i press the SAVE button (the one that doesn't send emails) appears and then disappears only 1 second after. It was supposed to only close when i press the button to close. The other button works correctly.

This is the code that i'm using:

```
        $.modal({
            content: $('#' + modalErrorId),
            title: 'Informa\u00E7\u00E3o',
            maxWidth: 500,
            buttons: modalButtons,
            zIndex: 500,
        });
```

Along with this:

```
$.ajax( {
   type: "POST",
   url: form.attr('action'),
   data: form.serialize(),
   success: function( response ) {
   openModal('modalSuccessMessage');
   }
});
```

Comment: then there is another event gets triggered as soon as the modal appeared, can you post the whole code?

Comment: There's no event triggered after the modal appears. The ajax code calls the openModal function (the first block of code) and nothing else =\

Comment: Though, those two snippets aren't enough, have you looked at the console? But i'm guessing you may be missing `return false` or `e.preventDefault()` line in your code.

Comment: In fact i don't have any of these codes anywhere. Where is that supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

OK, try either

```
$.ajax( {
   type: "POST",
   url: form.attr('action'),
   data: form.serialize(),
   success: function( response ) {
   openModal('modalSuccessMessage');
   }
});    
return false;
```

or

```
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax( {
   type: "POST",
   url: form.attr('action'),
   data: form.serialize(),
   success: function( response ) {
   openModal('modalSuccessMessage');
   }
});
```

You might have the code like,

```
$('#buttonid').on('click', function(e){
    // ajax call
});
```

or

```
$('#formid').on('submit', function(e){
    // ajax call
});
```

If i guessed correctly, the reason is

after modal appeared the form gets submitted in a regular way, which causes to refresh the page, therefor the DOM is being refreshed, therefore the modal disappears. `return false` or `e.preventDefault()` prevents the form to be submitted in a regular way.

Comment: Still haven't worked!! I don't think the problem is missing the return false. As i said before, when i press the other button (the one that also send an email) it works fine. The unique difference between the buttons is the email send. Plus, when the modal disappear, when i click the button again the hidden modal appears behind the new modal!

Comment: @Psyvenon It is better to post your whole code, otherwise cant determine the problem.